# How to get the ID (auto increment) of a record about to be uploaded?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-3

I am using Laravel 3. I have a form, and 2 tables. One table has an AUTO INCREMENT ID and I want to give this ID to the second table. eg.

table1

ID: Auto increment
title:

text:

date:

table2

ID: Auto increment
t1_ID: table1->ID

text:

Is it possible somehow?
I think I can get the ID of the last record in table1 and add 1 to it in the controller, but maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: D you want to pass ID before insertion into table A or after?

Comment: Don't try to anticipate the last ID+1, Insert the record into table1 with its autoincremented column, get the last ID that was used for that insert, then add the record to table2 with the retrieved autoincremented value

Comment: @Stoleg yes! I want to pass ID before insertion, so I can insert to the other table too with one button.

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION #1

This sounds like you need to use a trigger. To be safe you should use an AFTER INSERT trigger because you cannot predict if the autoincrement will increment more than once in the event of some unforeseen error during an INSERT.

Perhaps the trigger should look something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$   
CREATE TRIGGER table1_ai AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO table2 (t1_ID) VALUES (NEW.ID);
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

That way, the ID is safely placed in `table2`, knowing that the ID is in actual use in `table1`.

## SOLUTION #2

You could retrieve the ID using the information_schema. How?

Suppose the table is `mydb.table1`. You can quickly get the next auto_increment value like this:

```
SELECT auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' and table_name='table1';
```

This could be risky to retrieve if `mydb.table1` experiences high-volume writes

## EPILOGUE

You should go with `SOLUTION #1`, since implementing the trigger would handle the ID's placement in two tables without you having to code it.

Comment: More importantly, trigger will gurantee that autoincrement value will not change while row(s) being inserted into table B.